# 3-hour Transit in Beijing with two separate airline tickets

Tags: transit, beijing

I will be flying from Sydney to Beijing with China Eastern and taking a connection in Beijing 3 hours later with Air Astana to Bishkek (Kyrgistan). I will take only hand luggage with me and would like to make use of the 24-hour visa free scheme.
Looking at the airport map I realised both airlines operate in Terminal 2. I will have to get a boarding pass for the Air Astana flight in Beijing. Does this mean I can stay within transit in T2 and get the boarding pass there at a transit booth?